# Scala: give a constructor an enumeration and a function that takes that enumeration as a parameter

Tags: scala, enums

I'm wondering if there is any way to write the following in Scala:

```
class Test(enumeration:Enumeration, f:enumeration.Value=>String){

 // add fields here

}
```

Comment: Do you mean _any_ enumeration, or a _specific_ enumeration (which extends  `scala.Enumeration`)?

Comment: Any Enumeration - or rather a generic enumeration

Comment: There's a bug in the bug in the compiler bug that prevents you from doing this in the first place, btw. If `Test` is not a case class, then `val enumeration: Enumeration = null /* same name */; val f: enumeration.Value => String = null /* same name */; class Test(enumeration: Enumeration)(f: enumeration.Value => String)` works. It's filthy, but it's the most type-safe. This is the bug in the bug. The bug in the bug in the bug is that this won't work if `Test` is a case class. [Source](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5238#issuecomment-228075109)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Test[A <: Enumeration](val enumeration: A, f: A#Value => String) {
  // class body
}
```

Comment: Cool, ty. Could you explain how "<:" is different from ":" in the generic statement?

Comment: `A <: B` means that `A` is a subtype of `B`. See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/upper-type-bounds.html. `A : B` is a context bound (https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html) that means that an implicit instance of `B[A]` is available.